# How to run if-else statement on a loop within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column name1, I want to run an if-else statement to break out the lastname with special character '-' and output them like name2 and name3, how do I do that?

```
import pandas as pd 

d = {
    'name1': ['Braund', 'Cummings-Johnson', 'Heikkinen-Smith'],
    'name2': ['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen'],
    'name3': ['Braund', 'Johnson', 'Smith']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: You don't need a loop here; if you can't do this with an elementwise operation over the whole series (you can, but it may not be obvious—see, e.g., `df.name1.str.find('-')`), you can at least do it with `apply`. For example, look at what `df.name1.apply(lambda s: '-' in s)` gives you, and then what `df[df.name1.apply(lambda s: '-' in s)]` gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is designed to let you apply operations to entire columns rather than use a for-loop like you're describing.  One method you might be looking for is `str.split()` with `expand=True`:

```
>>> df.name1.str.split('-', expand=True)
           0        1
0     Braund     None
1   Cummings  Johnson
2  Heikkinen    Smith
```

Notice that names without a hyphen will be given `None` for the second element.  You could also filter down to only hyphenated last names first:

```
>>> df.loc[df.name1.str.contains('-'), 'name1'].str.split('-', expand=True)
           0        1
1   Cummings  Johnson
2  Heikkinen    Smith
```

To rename the columns:

```
df.loc[df.name1.str.contains('-'), 'name1']\
    .str.split('-', expand=True)\
    .rename(columns={0: 'name2', 1: 'name3'})
```

Lastly, if you really need to mimic exactly your example, you could use `ffill()`:

```
>>> df.name1.str.split('-', expand=True).ffill(axis=1)
           0        1
0     Braund   Braund
1   Cummings  Johnson
2  Heikkinen    Smith
```